# SwiftUI Custom Environment Value

Tags: swift, swiftui, environment

I try to make custom environment key to read its value as shown in the code below, I read many resources about how to make it and all have the same approach.
Example Code

```
struct Custom_EnvironmentValues: View {
    
     @State private var isSensitive = false

     var body: some View {
         VStack {
             // Update the value here <---
             Toggle(isSensitive ? "Sensitive": "Not sensitive", isOn: $isSensitive)
             PasswordField(password: "123456")
                 .isSensitive(isSensitive)

         }.padding()
     }
}
```

```
struct PasswordField: View {
    
    let password: String
    @Environment(\.isSensitive) private var isSensitive
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text("Password")
            Text(password)
                 // It should update the UI here but that not happened <---
                .foregroundColor(isSensitive ? .red : .green)
                .redacted(reason: isSensitive ? .placeholder: [])
            
        }
    }
}
```

```
// 1
private struct SensitiveKey: EnvironmentKey {
    static let defaultValue: Bool = false
}
// 2
extension EnvironmentValues {
    var isSensitive: Bool {
        get { self[SensitiveKey.self] }
        set { self[SensitiveKey.self] = newValue }
    }
}
// 3
extension View {
    func isSensitivePassword(_ value: Bool) -> some View {
        environment(\.isSensitive, value)
    }
}
```

When I try to make a custom environment value and read it, its not work, the key value not update at all.

Comment: This code works fine.

Comment: Did you try it? do you think there is an issue in Xcode prevent the code work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to inject into the `environment`

```
struct Custom_EnvironmentValues: View {
    
     @State private var isSensitive = false

     var body: some View {
         VStack {
             Toggle(isSensitive ? "Sensitive": "Not sensitive", isOn: $isSensitive)
                 
             PasswordField(password: "123456")
             .isSensitivePassword(isSensitive) //your function name
         }.padding()

     }
}
```

Comment: When I use ".environment(\.isSensitive, isSensitive)" its work fine, but when using ".isSensitive(isSensitive)" the function its not work and its important to me using the function because its eliminate update views issue.

Comment: @AmmarAhmad look at the comment I included your function is called `.isSensitivePassword(isSensitive)`

Comment: Oh, I get it. I thought `.isSensitive` was a typo, but you’re trying to get non-compiling code to work. By definition, that is impossible! 

Comment: @Jessy this code compiles.

Comment: Not you. The OP. Your answer is just confusing and somewhat wrong.

Comment: @loremipsum your comment is write the function I should call it is ".isSensitivePassword(isSensitive)" & not ".isSensitive(isSensitive)", I defined two function so I mixed up, your answer is right.

Comment: @AmmarAhmad the second one doesn’t exist in the code it won’t work

Comment: @loremipsum I wrote it in my code in another file so I mixed up between them, If note the first example code I use the second one ".isSensitive(isSensitive)", not ".isSensitivePassword(isSensitive)".